# Allow DNS queries to bind in iptables

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, bind

I have a DNS server up and running with configured single DNS zone for **example.com**
The following command, ran on the server returns the configured DNS Zone records:

**# dig example.com @ns1.example.com**

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.         IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.  10800   IN      A       10.0.0.1

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.  10800   IN      NS      ns2.example.com.
example.com.  10800   IN      NS      ns1.example.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.example.com. 10800 IN     A       10.0.0.1
ns2.example.com. 10800 IN     A       10.0.0.1
```

My **/etc/hosts** file:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com www.example.com
127.0.0.1 ns1.example.com ns2..example.com
```

When I try to query the DNS server from other server I get:
**$ dig example.com @10.0.0.1**

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

The actual public IP address of the server is substituted with 10.0.0.1
I believe that most probably the issue is caused by iptables filtration, since the DNS service responds to local queries.
Here are my iptables rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 14 packets, 1498 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1      259  157K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2      325 26717 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3     287K  149M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4    14721  872K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
5      165  7988 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 48 packets, 2949 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1      259  157K ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2     292K   46M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:22
3    16605 1195K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            8.8.8.8             udp dpt:53
4      130  9822 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
5      430 18880 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443
6      342  148K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80 state ESTABLISHED
```

I have tried to allow incoming/outgoing connections on port 53 both TCP and UDP using the following rules, but unfortunately the DNS service is still not reachable from the Internet:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --cstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Here is a TCPDUMP:

```
[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump port 53 and host {my_ip}
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
08:03:43.011650 IP {my_ip} > {server_hostname}.domain: Flags [S], seq 3026720770, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 396679618 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
08:03:44.006447 IP {my_ip} > {server_hostname}.domain: Flags [S], seq 3026720770, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 396679718 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
08:03:46.006615 IP {my_ip} > {server_hostname}.domain: Flags [S], seq 3026720770, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 396679918 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
08:03:50.016643 IP {my_ip} > {server_hostname}.domain: Flags [S], seq 3026720770, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 396680319 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
08:03:58.026589 IP {my_ip} > {server_hostname}.domain: Flags [S], seq 3026720770, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 396681120 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
08:04:14.066598 IP {my_ip} > {server_hostname}.domain: Flags [S], seq 3026720770, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 396682724 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
08:04:46.186714 IP {my_ip} > {server_hostname}.domain: Flags [S], seq 3026720770, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 396685936 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
7 packets captured
7 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Any hints will be appreciated :)

Comment: i wouldn't bother with `NEW` or `conntrack` on `UDP` connections.

Comment: check wich IP bind is allow to respond query from. In named.conf (or any file there's a include statement for in named.conf) search for somethint like options {
allow
-
query { 192.168.100/24 };
allow
-
recurs
ion { 192.168.100/24 };

Comment: listen-on port 53 { {public_ip}; 127.0.0.1; };

Answer (score 1):

I think i got your problem, iptables rules corresponding to OUTPUT chain is blocking udp 53 port traffic from interface which has been assigned 10.0.0.1 ip.

Please use the following command to allow outgoing DNS requests.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

**First update**

Please check if bind is listening on all interface i.e named.conf
has listen-on { any; };

Comment: Still: ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: Please go through the First update.

Comment: Currenly it is ** listen-on port 53 { localhost; };**, but I have tried with ** listen-on port 53 { any; };** as well, no success :(

Comment: Did you restarted the bind daemon after changing the configuration?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: This error occurs when either bind is not running on the server or it is inaccessible either due to iptables setting or client machine is unreachable to server.Can you able to ping the server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36520/discussion-between-user2632528-and-georgi-tsvetanov-tsenov).

Comment: Yes, I am able to ping the server and telnet to 22 and 80, but I am not able to query it for DNS Zone